# Automatic embeded script

Tags: ajax, hosting

I have a free website on 000webhost. The problem is it automatically puts its analytics code in all my files. It does not show up everywhere but it causes me problem when I use AJAX calls and display the returned data in a div, it displays the data as well as that particular code. Is there any type of method to avoid this or make this code invisible. 
Also when I used Google webmaster tools, when it crawls my robots.txt file the code is also shown to the crawler on that file also which is a text file and it returns error.
Please help!
Here is the link to my website:
[Portfolio](http://sqhr.comule.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your hosting provider seems to inject the following line at the end of some requests:

```
<!-- www.000webhost.com Analytics Code -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://analytics.hosting24.com/count.php"></script>
<noscript><a href="http://www.hosting24.com/"><img src="http://analytics.hosting24.com/count.php" alt="web hosting" /></a></noscript>
<!-- End Of Analytics Code -->
```

The injection point of their code is simply at the end of the request. When I checked, it meant that it was outside the HTML tag (and thus broke HTML syntax validity.

I see 2 possible solutions:

1. Work the issue out with them.
2. Find a work-around (your provider might be injecting this content on when they detect certaint type of requests. If you find out that they only inject the content on requests to URLs ending in .html (for example), you could try changing the destination of your AJAX call towards another URL)